# How can I create a custom field type for a select with multiple values?

Tags: 8, entities

I need a field type with 3 select in it. The field type is created and works like a charm but I'd like one of these select may have multiple values. What must I change? I add '#multiple' => TRUE, in the widget. But I can't save my values. I should probably change the type of field in the FieldType but how? Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Provides a field type of resource.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Resource"),
 *   default_formatter = "resource_formatter",
 *   default_widget = "resource_widget",
 * )
 */
class ResourceItem extends FieldItemBase {

  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties = [];
    $properties['topic'] = DataDefinition::create('string');
    $properties['material'] = DataDefinition::create('string');
    $properties['add_infos'] = DataDefinition::create('string');
    $properties['columns_display'] = DataDefinition::create('string');

    return $properties;
  }

  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return [
      'columns' => [
        'topic' => [
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '255',
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ],
        'material' => [
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '255',
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ],
        'add_infos' => [
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '255',
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ],
        'columns_display' => [
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '255',
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isEmpty() {
    $value1 = $this->get('topic')->getValue();
    $value2 = $this->get('material')->getValue();
    $value3 = $this->get('add_infos')->getValue();
    $value4 = $this->get('columns_display')->getValue();
    return empty($value1) && empty($value2) && empty($value3) && empty($value4);
  }

}
```

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'topic_widget' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "resource_widget",
 *   label = @Translation("Resource default"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "resource"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ResourceDefaultWidget extends WidgetBase {

  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = \Drupal::config('resources.config');


    $json_topics = file_get_contents($config->get('global_config.url_api') . '/topics');
    $topics = Json::decode($json_topics);
    $options_topics[0] = '--- Choose topic ---';
    foreach ($topics as $key => $topic) {
      $options_topics[$topic['name']] = ucfirst($topic['name']);
    }
    $element['topic'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Topic'),
      '#description' => t('List of topics from osteoporosis-foundation'),
      '#options' => $options_topics,
    ];


    $json_materials = file_get_contents($config->get('global_config.url_api') . '/materials');
    $materials = Json::decode($json_materials);
    $options_mat[0] = '--- Choose material ---';
    foreach ($materials as $key => $material) {
      $options_mat[$material['name']] = ucfirst($material['name']);
    }
    $element['material'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Material'),
      '#description' => t('List of materials from osteoporosis-foundation'),
      '#options' => $options_mat,
    ];


    $json_add_infos = file_get_contents($config->get('global_config.url_api') . '/additional-information');
    $add_infos = Json::decode($json_add_infos);
    $options_add_infos[0] = '--- Choose additional information ---';
    foreach ($add_infos as $key => $info) {
      $options_add_infos[$info['name']] = ucfirst($info['name']);
    }
    $element['add_infos'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Additional Information'),
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
      '#description' => t('List of additional information from osteoporosis-foundation'),
      '#options' => $options_add_infos,
    ];


    $element['columns_display'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Number of column to display'),
      '#options' => [
        'null'     => '--- Choose column(s) to display ---',
        'col-md-3' => '1 column',
        'col-md-6' => '2 columns',
        'col-md-9' => '3 columns',
        'col-md-12' => '4 columns',
      ],
    ];


    //setting default value to all fields from above
    $childs = Element::children($element);
    foreach ($childs as $child) {
      $element[$child]['#default_value'] = isset($items[$delta]->{$child}) ? $items[$delta]->{$child} : NULL;
    }

    return $element;
  }

}
```

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'resource_formatter' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "resource_formatter",
 *   label = @Translation("Resource default"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "resource"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ResourceDefaultFormatter extends FormatterBase{

  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $config = \Drupal::config('resources.config');

    $element = [];

    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $column_display = $item->columns_display;

      $topics = 'topics=' . str_replace(' ', '+', $item->topic);
      $materials = '&materials=' . str_replace(' ', '+', $item->material);
      $additional_info = '&additional_info=' . str_replace(' ', '+', $item->add_infos);

      $json_all  = file_get_contents($config->get('global_config.url_api').'/all' . '?' . $topics . $materials . $additional_info);

      $all_content       = Json::decode($json_all);

      foreach ($all_content['rows'] as $key => $content){
        $type_explode = explode('-', $content['type']);
        $type = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', trim(end($type_explode))));

        switch($type){
          case ('remote_videos'):
            $element[] = [
              '#theme' => 'video',
              '#resource' => $content,
              '#column_display' => $column_display
            ];
            break;
          default:
            $element[] = [
              '#theme' => 'file',
              '#resource' => $content,
              '#column_display' => $column_display
            ];
        }
      }
    }

    return $element;
  }

}
```

Comment: Posting the code you have written so far is helpful. Also, read this article: https://ixis.co.uk/blog/drupal-8-creating-field-types-multiple-values

Comment: Setting '#multiple' returns an array you can't store in a string without serializing it.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I do this?

Comment: Serialize in [WidgetBase::massageFormValues](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetBase.php/function/WidgetBase%3A%3AmassageFormValues/9.0.x). Unserialize when setting the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update my code following the 4k4's comment and now it works. Thanks for your help

```php
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'topic_widget' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "resource_widget",
 *   label = @Translation("Resource default"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "resource"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ResourceDefaultWidget extends WidgetBase {

  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = \Drupal::config('resources.config');


    $json_topics = file_get_contents($config->get('global_config.url_api') . '/topics');
    $topics = Json::decode($json_topics);
    $options_topics[0] = '--- Choose topic ---';
    foreach ($topics as $key => $topic) {
      $options_topics[$topic['name']] = ucfirst($topic['name']);
    }
    $element['topic'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Topic'),
      '#description' => t('List of topics from osteoporosis-foundation'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->topic) ? $items[$delta]->topic : NULL,
      '#options' => $options_topics,
    ];


    $json_materials = file_get_contents($config->get('global_config.url_api') . '/materials');
    $materials = Json::decode($json_materials);
    $options_mat[0] = '--- Choose material ---';
    foreach ($materials as $key => $material) {
      $options_mat[$material['name']] = ucfirst($material['name']);
    }
    $element['material'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Material'),
      '#description' => t('List of materials from osteoporosis-foundation'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->material) ? $items[$delta]->material : NULL,
      '#options' => $options_mat,
    ];


    $json_add_infos = file_get_contents($config->get('global_config.url_api') . '/additional-information');
    $add_infos = Json::decode($json_add_infos);
    $options_add_infos[0] = '--- Choose additional information ---';
    foreach ($add_infos as $key => $info) {
      $options_add_infos[$info['name']] = ucfirst($info['name']);
    }
    $element['add_infos'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Additional Information'),
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
      '#description' => t('List of additional information from osteoporosis-foundation'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->add_infos) ? unserialize($items[$delta]->add_infos) : NULL,
      '#options' => $options_add_infos,
    ];


    $element['columns_display'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Number of columns to display'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->columns_display) ? $items[$delta]->columns_display : NULL,
      '#options' => [
        'null'     => '--- Choose column(s) to display ---',
        'col-md-12' => '1 column',
        'col-md-9' => '2 columns',
        'col-md-6' => '3 columns',
        'col-md-3' => '4 columns',
      ],
    ];


    //setting default value to all fields from above
    /*$childs = Element::children($element);
    foreach ($childs as $child) {
      $element[$child]['#default_value'] = isset($items[$delta]->{$child}) ? $items[$delta]->{$child} : NULL;
    }*/

    return $element;
  }

  public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if($values[0]['add_infos'] != '0'){
      $values[0]['add_infos'] = serialize($values[0]['add_infos']);
    }

    return $values;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code updates in the answer.